# c# there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#

I'm kind of new to C# and i don't really know if I'm doing this correctly. So i have two forms, one of creating a character and one for the main game that I'm making. I have a two radio buttons to choose a character gender on one form. Now i want to pass whatever gender the user chose as text onto a label on the main game form.

On my CharacterCreation form i have created the following method:

```
public string characterGender(string Male, string Female, int id)
{                  
    String genderFemale = Female;
    String genderMale = Male;
    int ID = id;

    if (radiobtngenderFemale.Checked == true)
    {
        id = 1;
        return Female;   
    }
    else if (radiobtngenderMale.Checked == true)
    {
        id = 2;
        return Male;
    }
}
```

On my main game form i have the following code:

```
public partial class MainGame : Form
{
    private CharacterCreation _characterCreation;

    public MainGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        _characterCreation = new CharacterCreation();        

        lbl1.Text = _characterCreation.characterGender()
    }

    private void MainGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error:
"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter"

I've looked at a lot of other topics but couldn't really find an answer.

Comment: This is not the full error message.

Comment: When calling `_characterCreation.characterGender()` you have to supply it with your 3 parameters `string Male, string Female, int id` by writing values that you want to give them inside the function call brackets, that are empty in your case, which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: I know you are a beginner but maybe take a step back and look at your logic.  The method `characterGender()` takes 3 parameters (`string Male, string Female, int id`).  You dont pass those parameters when you call the method.  Also the `genderFemale` and `genderMale` variables arent used at all in the method, whats the point of them?  You also don't need to check in your if statements `if(radiobtngenderMale.Checked == true)` you can just check `if(radiobtngenderMale.Checked)`

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the method _characterCreation.characterGender()

You need to pass the declared parameters.

Or remove the parameters from your method

```
characterGender(string Male, string Female, int id)
```

To

```
 characterGender()
```

Comment: I can only add to that, that Windows Forms is not the right tool to develop a game. While turnbased singleplayer and hotseat multiplayer games are possible, even those have limits. Solitaire might well be the upper bound of what is possible in Windows Forms. In general you should be using a dedicated approach liek XNA in .NET Framework or any of the 3 ways for .NET Core (https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/gaming)

Comment: Then you havent heard about Aurora 4x. Anyhow im not really looking to make a great game just practicing and learning